# interpret tradingview pine-script self-referencing variable value

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I need someone interpret or convert this line of pine-script code to any other language please:

```
TrendUp = close[1] > TrendUp[1] ? max(100, TrendUp[1]) : 100
```

Actually the weird part is `TrendUp[1]`. how it is evaluated and what is its value?

The full code is:

```
Up = hl2 - atr(1)
Dn = hl2 + atr(1)

TrendUp = close[1] > TrendUp[1] ? max(Up, TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown = close[1] < TrendDown[1] ? min(Dn, TrendDown[1]) : Dn
Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1 : close < TrendUp[1] ? -1 : nz(Trend[1], 0)

plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=1000, minheight=50, transp=85)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=1000, minheight=50, transp=85)
```

And the result on the chart are those long vertical red/green arrows:

[image: vdub indicator signal provider]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in pinescript is called [History Reference Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator). You can use this operator to access historical values of a variable.

For example, `close[3]` will return whatever the close price was three bars ago. Note that the history reference operator will return `n/a` for the very first bar of the chart.

After reading the link I provided, to understand the below code I suggest you plot some of those variables.

`TrendUp = close[1] > TrendUp[1] ? max(Up, TrendUp[1]) : Up`

You should have a look at what values `close[1]`, `TrendUp[1]` and `Up` have. Simplest way to do is create a new indicator with `overlay=false` and remove all plot statements. Then add the below code to the very end of the script.

```
plot(series=TrendUp, color=green)
plot(series=TrendUp[1], color=red)
plot(series=close[1], color=orange)
plot(series=Up, color=white)
```

Below image is a screenshot from the very first bar of the chart. As I said, `TrendUp[1]` and `close[1]` have the value `n/a`. So, `close[1] > TrendUp[1]` evaluates to `false` and `UpTrend` gets the value of `Up`, which is `85.1` at that time.

[image]

So, this is how you start. Then hover your mouse over the next bars and keep looking at the values. You can also plot the `close` price to get a better understanding.

Remember, `TrendUp[1]` refers to the value of `TrendUp` one bar ago. So, there is a one bar delay between the red and green plots.